# Auto delete excel file if it renamed

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am working on Excel file of salary. I want to delete this Excel file automatically after rename it. I mean if anyone open it after rename then it will be automatically deleted. My code is working, but it also deletes it without rename the file.

```
Private Sub workbook_open()
    Dim xFileName As String
    xFileName = "Salary.xlsm"
    If xFileName <> "True" Then
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Next ws
        Sheets("User").Visible = xlVeryHidden
        Sheets("Pass").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    End If

    If xFileName <> "False" Then
        Me.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
        MsgBox "File Name Changed- iTach"
        Kill Me.FullName
        Application.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @iTech This is not a VBScript

Comment: O Yaaaa. Sorry for that. Post updated now. I have only above code. If you know about this please provide me solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code..

```
        Private Sub workbook_open()
        Dim xFileName As String
        xFileName = "salary.xlsm"
        If xFileName = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Next ws
            Sheets("User").Visible = xlVeryHidden
            Sheets("Pass").Visible = xlVeryHidden
        Else
            Me.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
            MsgBox "File Name Changed- iTach"
            Kill Me.FullName
            Application.Quit
        End If
        End Sub
```